# Moded apk to Google Play | You uploaded a debuggable APK

Tags: android

I uploaded a moded and RECOMPILED VERSION of an apk to market.
but when i try to upload a updated version of it, it says

You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play

i used apktool to zipaline and sign, then used apk-signer too.
these worked fine for me few days ago.

sorry about my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the debugging to false in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:debuggable="false"
```

Comment: I did that too.still no luck.

Comment: I don't think your issue persist if you have signed your app from own keystore file and add this `debuggable` to `false`. Did you sign your application from own created keystore ?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR.IT WORKED.
YOU ARE A GOD.
i tired a solution for days now.